# rails and sql where IS NOT NULL not working properly with join. Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.8.7 - mysql 5

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, inner-join

I have 3 tables & models:
brands
brand_data_records
and 
brand_data_records_brands - the join table

In rails i want all brand_data_records for a given date range for a given brand where a given attribute is not null in the db.

So I have:

```
BrandDataRecord.find(:all, :select => column_match, :joins => :brands, :conditions => ["brand_data_records_brands.brand_id = ? and date_retrieved >= ? AND date_retrieved <= ? and ? IS NOT NULL",brand.id,start_date,end_date,column_match])
```

This generates this sql:

```
  SELECT sentiment FROM `brand_data_records` INNER JOIN `brand_data_records_brands` ON `brand_data_records_brands`.brand_data_record_id = `brand_data_records`.id INNER JOIN `brands` ON `brands`.id = `brand_data_records_brands`.brand_id WHERE (brand_data_records_brands.brand_id = 330516084 and date_retrieved >= '2011-05-02' AND date_retrieved <= '2011-06-01' and 'sentiment' IS NOT NULL)
```

Which generally works, but it gives back a bunch of extra records that have a null value. I think its something to do with the joins, if I remove them with sql only it works fine, but im not sure how to fix in rails (or even in sql for that fact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mean to reference the column:

```
 `sentiment` IS NOT NULL
```

What you're doing inadvertently is asserting that the string `'sentiment'` is not null, which of course it will never be. Passing in `:sentiment` or `'sentiment'.to_sym'` in your conditions should fix this as symbols get escaped with backquotes on conversion.

Comment: I tried the symbol approach and mysql is : SELECT sentiment FROM `brand_data_records` INNER JOIN `brand_data_records_brands` ON `brand_data_records_brands`.brand_data_record_id = `brand_data_records`.id INNER JOIN `brands` ON `brands`.id = `brand_data_records_brands`.brand_id WHERE (brand_data_records_brands.brand_id = 330516084 and date_retrieved >= '2011-05-02' AND date_retrieved <= '2011-06-01' and '--- :sentiment\n' IS NOT NULL)  and that has same issue. I did try hardcoding sentiment in the sql string and that works fine, so you are on the right track of the problem...

Comment: If I make sentiment a symbol and do this: matching_records = BrandDataRecord.find(:all, :select => column_match, :joins => :brands, :conditions => ["brand_data_records_brands.brand_id = ? and date_retrieved >= ? AND date_retrieved <= ? and #{column_match} IS NOT NULL",brand.id,start_date,end_date])
 then it works. This seems ugly, but at least it works!

Comment: Yeah, I meant "a string will never be NULL", not that it would never not be.

Comment: Ah, the symbol method works in Sequel. If you want to be safe, you would probably use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote_table_name(column_match)` but that's even uglier. Just watch out for column names that match SQL reserved keywords like `COUNT` or those with spaces in them. Also be **absolutely** sure that `column_match` is not taken directly from user input.